# How to change the scroll distance of the arrow QPushButton in a QScrollbar?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qscrollbar

How can I change the distance scrolled when I click on the QPushButton on a scrollbar?

[image: screenshot of the GUI with a scrollbar on the right and the bottom arrow-down / scroll-down button marked]

It goes 1 by 1 and I would like to change it to 5 by 5 for example.
I already tried `setPageStep` and `setSingleStep` but they didn't work.

Comment: I tried with this [minimal reproducible example](https://hastebin.com/share/qewujaxape.scss), and it seems that using `setSingleStep` will only work after calling `show`. Could you verify if that is the case with your program as well? If not then please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), OS and Qt version you're using. I tested on KDE Neon using Qt 6.5.0 and 6.5.2.